# Question about the size of tournament in Tournament selection in Genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

In the tournament selection, k = tournament size, what happens if k = population size and what happens if k = 1?

Answer (score 1):

Tournament size modifies selection pressure during evolution.

In case tournament size is equal to the size of population the best individual in whole population will be picked. This will cause stuck in local optimum.

Case when tournament size is equal to one is not valid. You have to pick at least 2 individuals to compare them. 
But if you mean picking one random individual as parent selection strategy ... This will cause stuck of evolution process from the begging.

Selecting right tournament size depends on population size and problem you solve.